# How does ransack search works on an array list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I am using Rails 4.2.5, Ruby 2.2, ransack.
I am trying to implement search functionality using Ransack. I have something like:

```
emails = ["abc@abc.com", "a@a.com", "b@b.com"]
users_list = emails.map{|a| User.where(email: a).first}
checked_in_users = Kaminari.paginate_array(users_list)
```

This gives me proper list of users in the page. But if I want to search by email, what should I do ?

```
@q = checked_in_users.ransack params[:q]
```

This gives me:

```
"NoMethodError (undefined method `ransack' for #<Array"
```

HAML code:

```
= search_form_for [@q], url: users_path(some_id: id) do |form|
  = form.text_field :user_name_or_user_email_cont, placeholder: 'Name or email', class: 'form-control'
```

What would be the correct way to do it with ransack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search the entire list of users, you could do something like this:

```
@q = User.ransack(params[:q])
@users = @q.result.page(params[:page])
```

You want to call `ransack` on your model prior to adding pagination. Once you have the ransack result, you can add pagination. This section of the documentation shows you [how to handle pagination with ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#problem-with-distinct-selects). In its most basic form, this is [how you can use ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#in-your-controller).

---

Also, it looks like you have some odd code in your example. Apologies if I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

When you call `emails.map{|a| User.where(email: a).first}`, you're making a where query 3 times in this case and returning an array of 3 models. Ransack won't operate on that array.

I would change it to something like this in your case:

```
emails = ["abc@abc.com", "a@a.com", "b@b.com"]
@q = User.where(email: emails).ransack(params[:q])
@checked_in_users = @q.result.page(params[:page])
```

Just know that you'd be searching from an array of users with emails of "abc@abc.com", "a@a.com", and "b@b.com". If you search with your ransack form for "bob@example.com", you wouldn't get any search results. This may not be what you want.

Comment: Hi @Derek... The second answer worked for me. Though I have another problem stated with this. I don't know should I post it here or open a new ticket. I am writing this above code in a different controller and different view other than users. With the above list, I am getting this error:

        **ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user_name_or_user_email_cont' for Ransack::Search<class: User, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search):**

Comment: @Avinash What columns are on your User model? If you need to post quite a few more details, you may want to open a new question.

Comment: Sure I will open a new question & post the link here.

Comment: Here is the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48274694/ransack-search-error