# Ransack search error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I am using Rails 4.2.5, Ruby 2.2, ransack. I am trying to implement search functionality using Ransack. I have something like:

These code are in abc_controller.rb:

```
def checked_users
  emails = ["abc@abc.com", "a@a.com", "b@b.com"]
  users_list = User.where("email in (?)", emails)
  @q = users_list.ransack params[:q]
end
```

These are the code in checked_users.html.haml: (Ignore the url path here. Its correct, for now I have changed it)

```
= search_form_for @q, url: checked_users_path(some_id: id) do |form|
  = form.text_field :user_name_or_user_email_cont, placeholder: 'Name or email', class: 'form-control'
```

In routes.rb:

```
resources :xyz do
  resources :mno do
    get 'checked_users', controller: 'abc', action: 'checked_users'
  end
end
```

With these code I am getting an error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user_name_or_user_email_cont' for Ransack::Search<class: User, base: Grouping <combinator: and>>:Ransack::Search):
```

Not sure why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're searching for users, I think you can get rid of the `user` prefix on the text field.

For example, you have:

```
form.text_field :user_name_or_user_email_cont, placeholder: 'Name or email', class: 'form-control'
```

Changing it to something like this should work:

```
form.text_field :name_or_email_cont, placeholder: 'Name or email', class: 'form-control'
```

Also, I would consider using ransack's `search_field` instead of `text_field` if you can.

---

Here's some additional information. I believe you only need to use a prefix like `user` if you want to search associations. For example, let's say you have a user and toy model like this:

```
class User
  # attribute: first_name, String
  # attribute: last_name, String
  has_many :toys
end

class Toy
  # attribute: name, String
end
```

Now, you can perform a ransack search on the user or the user's toys. Here's how you'd use `search_field` to do this. In this case, `first_name` and `last_name` refer to the user, and `toys_name` refers to a toy's name.

```
form.search_field :first_name_or_last_name_or_toys_name_cont, placeholder: "First Name, Last Name, or Toy's Name", class: 'form-control'
```